# Does ASP.NET Core WebAPI not support deferred execution / lazy evaluation when returning collections?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper, lazy-evaluation, asp.net-core-webapi

I've just run into what I'd consider a slightly odd bit of behaviour when writing a C# ASP.NET Core WebAPI controller.

Consider the following controller method, which accepts a JSON body and produces an XML output (for reasons I won't go into):

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
[Route("api/route/to/data"]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetData([FromBody]IEnumerable<InputData> inputs)
{
    return HandleResponse(() => _repository.GetData(inputs));
}
```

And the following repository method:

```
public IEnumerable<OutputData> GetData(IEnumerable<InputData> inputs)
{
    foreach(var input in inputs)
    {
        string field1 = input.Field1;
        int field2 = input.Field2;

        const string sql = @"
            SELECT foo.bar, foo.baz
            FROM my_table foo
            WHERE foo.wubble = :field1
            AND foo.flob = :field2";

        yield return _repoBase.GetSingleValue<OutputData>(sql, new {field1, field2});
    }
}
```

(The _repoBase.GetSingleValue method is simply a dumb generic wrapper around Dapper's QueryFirstOrDefault method, and doesn't do anything fancy or complicated. Also I'm aware that using a loop in this way is not optimal, but it will do for the purpose of this example.)

If put a breakpoint in the controller, and then call this endpoint from Postman providing a simple JSON data in the body such as:

```
[{"field1":"wibble", "field2":123456}]
```

Then the breakpoint is hit, and the repo pulls back data as expected, and execution appears to fall through - however Postman reports that an HTTP 406 Not Acceptable status code was returned as a response, and no data is actually included.

However, if I force the IEnumerable to enumerate into a concrete collection before returning it:

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
[Route("api/route/to/data"]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetData([FromBody]IEnumerable<InputData> inputs)
{
    return HandleResponse(() => _repository.GetData(inputs).ToList());
}
```

Then I get a 200 OK back along with the data I expected.

I am of course aware of the concept of deferred execution / lazy evaluation when using IEnumerables and particularly `yield return`, however I would expect the framework to be intelligent enough to iterate any collections it is provided before spitting them out into the world. Is this actually expected behaviour, or a bug?

At the very least the response code it returns in this case is not very intuitive IMO - it had me checking my middleware setup thinking that I'd forgotten to add an output formatter or something.

**Edit 1:** Yes, I am wrapping the output into an ObjectResult.

**Edit 2**: The ObjectResult wrapping is actually done in this method - nothing special:

```
protected IActionResult HandleResponse<T>(Func<T> resultProvider)
{
    try
    {
        return new ObjectResult(resultProvider());
    }
    catch (OracleException oex)
    {
        // DB error handling - omitted for brevity.
        // Nothing is done to the collection here.
        int errorCode = 500 // This is actually mapped to whatever Oracle error code is returned, e.g. incorrect Oracle password = 403.
        return new StatusCodeResult(errorCode);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Unhandled Exception", e);
        return new StatusCodeResult(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you check Visual Studio's output window, do you see any exception? I would imagine an unhandled exception being thrown and somewhere that's getting converted to the HTTP 406

Comment: Interesting. When I remove the ToList and re-run the test, I see the following in the output window:


`warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
No output formatter was found for content type 'application/xml' to write the response.`

Comment: Is your action method above a direct copy and paste? Because that actually shouldn't compile. An `IEnumerable<OutputData>` is not an `IActionResult` (your return type). You should be returning something like `return Ok(_repository.GetData(inputs));`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You're correct - I actually omitted a wrapper class in the example that wraps the output into an ObjectResult - my bad.

Comment: Post that as well, since it may be part of the issue.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. It sounded like you had a custom class at play that wraps your enumerable in an `ObjectResult`, not just that you're return `ObjectResult` directly (based on your edit). If there is a custom class, post that class.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - see edits to OP.

Comment: So, do you actually have some XML formatter configured in your application? Your comment suggests that's the problem, and the HTTP 406 makes sense

Comment: Yep, the XML formatter is configured in the startup, and works fine if given an array or a list. Only passing in an unenumerated `IEnumerable` causes it to break in this way.

Comment: Interesting. I almost never utilize XML any more, so I didn't realize, but it seems `XmlSerializer` actually *does not* support enumerables, whereas they're perfectly fine with something like JSON.NET serialization. The suggested solution is calling `ToList()` on the enumerable, which of course, you've already found works. In other words, this is entirely due to returning XML. You'd have had no issues if your were returning JSON. Supposedly the `DataContractSerializer` does not have this issue, so you may want to switch out `XmlSerializer` with that, or just keep using `ToList()`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Isn't that an answer?

Comment: Well, technically, perhaps, but I didn't want to post it as one, because I haven't actually tested any of it. It's just based on anecdotal evidence I've found searching online.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Huh, just tried this with JSON and you're right - weird! Unfortunately I have to stick with XML due to restrictions on what is calling the service - I'll probably stick with using a `ToList()` rather than messing around with the middleware too much given that I've got it in a working state for now. Feel free to post this as an answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Sam FWIW, using `DataContractSerializer` is as simple as just calling `options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());` instead of `options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());`. You of course, then would need to add the `DataContract` attribute to any classes that will be serialized, so it's a little more effort involved. However, it may be worth it, since this is a non-intuitive issue that is likely to rear its head again. If you or another developer forgets to do `ToList()`, in another case, for example, and you may not even realize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Belatedly marking this as answered, with thanks to commenters above.

It turns out that this behaviour is specific to XML output formatters; they simply do not seem to support serialization of yield-backed `IEnumerable<T>` objects, at least in .NET Core.

I have tried using both `XmlSerializerOutputFormatter` and `XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter` as output formatters, with the same results.

Substituting either XML output formatter for the standard JSON formatter resolves the problem.

In my case, XML output is required, so as a workaround I am explicitly converting the `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>` as per my original post. The XML formatters are then able to correctly serialize the collection.